# "POST [...] 403" error (email sending with AJAX/jQuery)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm doing my resume on a website format, so I took a template on internet ([here](https://www.styleshout.com/free-templates/ceevee/)) and hosted it on bitbucket

However I can't establish the mail sending part, I get the "POST [...] 403" error like this in my browser console
Here -> https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2019/13/2/1553620586-console-log.png

Here is the sendEmail.php :

```
<?php

// Replace this with your own email address
$siteOwnersEmail = 'test@gmail.com';


if($_POST) {

   $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactName']));
   $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactEmail']));
   $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactSubject']));
   $contact_message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['contactMessage']));

   // Check Name
    if (strlen($name) < 2) {
        $error['name'] = "Please enter your name.";
    }
    // Check Email
    if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9&\'\.\-_\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z0-9\-]+\.)*+[a-z]{2}/is', $email)) {
        $error['email'] = "Please enter a valid email address.";
    }
    // Check Message
    if (strlen($contact_message) < 15) {
        $error['message'] = "Please enter your message. It should have at least 15 characters.";
    }
   // Subject
    if ($subject == '') { $subject = "Contact Form Submission"; }


   // Set Message
   $message .= "Email from: " . $name . "<br />";
    $message .= "Email address: " . $email . "<br />";
   $message .= "Message: <br />";
   $message .= $contact_message;
   $message .= "<br /> ----- <br /> This email was sent from your site's contact form. <br />";

   // Set From: header
   $from =  $name . " <" . $email . ">";

   // Email Headers
    $headers = "From: " . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: ". $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";


   if (!$error) {

      ini_set("sendmail_from", $siteOwnersEmail); // for windows server
      $mail = mail($siteOwnersEmail, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($mail) { echo "OK"; }
      else { echo "Something went wrong. Please try again."; }

    } # end if - no validation error

    else {

        $response = (isset($error['name'])) ? $error['name'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['email'])) ? $error['email'] . "<br /> \n" : null;
        $response .= (isset($error['message'])) ? $error['message'] . "<br />" : null;

        echo $response;

    } # end if - there was a validation error

}

?>
```

The contact form :

```
/*----------------------------------------------------*/
/*  contact form
------------------------------------------------------*/

   $('form#contactForm button.submit').click(function() {

      $('#image-loader').fadeIn();

      var contactName = $('#contactForm #contactName').val();
      var contactEmail = $('#contactForm #contactEmail').val();
      var contactSubject = $('#contactForm #contactSubject').val();
      var contactMessage = $('#contactForm #contactMessage').val();

      var data = 'contactName=' + contactName + '&contactEmail=' + contactEmail +
               '&contactSubject=' + contactSubject + '&contactMessage=' + contactMessage;

      $.ajax({

          type: "POST",
          url: "inc/sendEmail.php",
          data: data,
          success: function(msg) {

            // Message was sent
            if (msg == 'OK') {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').hide();
               $('#contactForm').fadeOut();
               $('#message-success').fadeIn();   
            }
            // There was an error
            else {
               $('#image-loader').fadeOut();
               $('#message-warning').html(msg);
                $('#message-warning').fadeIn();
            }

          }

      });
      return false;
   });
```

The HTML code :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="eight columns">
        <!-- form -->
        <form action="" method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactForm">
            <fieldset>
                <div>
                    <label for="contactName">Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactName" name="contactName">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="contactEmail">Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactEmail" name="contactEmail">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="contactSubject">Subject</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" size="35" id="contactSubject" name="contactSubject">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="contactMessage">Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="15" id="contactMessage" name="contactMessage"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="submit">Submit</button>
                    <span id="image-loader">
                        <img alt="" src="images/loader.gif">
                     </span>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form> <!-- Form End -->
        <!-- contact-warning -->
        <div id="message-warning"> Error boy</div>
        <!-- contact-success -->
        <div id="message-success">
            <i class="fas fa-check"></i>Your message was sent, thank you!<br>
        </div>
</div>
```

And the script part :

```
   <!-- Java Script
   ================================================== -->
  <!-- <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
 <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <!-- <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script> -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

   <script src="js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
   <script src="js/waypoints.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jquery.fittext.js"></script>
   <script src="js/magnific-popup.js"></script>
   <script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

(I have tried the commented parts but still same error)

You can see the expected results on the demo 
[here](https://www.styleshout.com/demo/?theme=ceevee) at the end of the page

Thanks for your help !

EDIT : Finally I changed and deployed my resume on Heroku. The problem was apparently coming from hosting it on Bitbucket

Comment: Please add the code into the question and not as images. You can us 4 spaces, or 3 ` s to format your code.

Comment: Don't post links .. Post **actual code** ..  Also a 403 is "Forbidden" so check to see permissions on the file, that the file *actually exists* and that your not trying to use AJAX from one domain to another without *crossdomain** turned on.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Chipster and @Zak !! Changed images to actual code as you asked, thought it would make the post too big but it didn't. I changed all the directories and files rights with a `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

Comment: The `chmod` still didn't work. And sorry but I didn't get the part on the "crossdomain*", let's say I'm new to this, the AJAX part is on the "contact form" code if you need something. I'm open to give you any info you need

Answer (score 0):

if you get a CORS error try adding "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"
in front of your URL.

Here is an example in javascript/html

```
var CORS = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/"


function loadDoc() {
var apiKey = getName();
var apiPw = getPass();
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
  myFunction(this);
}
};
 xhttp.open("GET", CORS + 
'https://brickset.com/api/v2.asmx/getThemes?' + 'Username=' + apiKey + 
, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Aaron lilly ! I tried adding "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/" in front of my URL but i got this message "**Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with**". I guess I have to put your code example but I don't know where x) A new file ?

Comment: i realized yours is php, which im not as familiar with, but my example is straight javascript. so could go wherever javascript goes. also make sure you are using the full https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/

so https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http:/yoursitehere.com

Comment: Still nothing even with your example in a .js file and with the full link like you showed me ;(